# Joomla 2.5.7 issues

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am having issues with a site that I am configuring. It all happens a few days ago. There hasn't been any changes to the styles other than configuring the layout in the category page (numbers of featured page, size of image).

- All paragraph in an articles turn out to be bold. Based on the editor, it is not bold.
- Most articles also turn out to be not part of the themes when viewed individually and links to the images automatically replaced to something like "category/item/images/article_img/" instead of "images/article_img/". However when I viewed the article on the K2 editor, articles is displayed as it is supposed to be.
- Most articles are not part of themes when viewed individually.

Below is an example of the issues that I am referring to:

Articles page displaying correctly:
http://bit.ly/1TVrpB1

Articles page not displaying correctly:
http://bit.ly/1Rs8Hun

What could possibly be the issue here? I am not able to figure out the root cause. Hope someone can advise me here.

Regards,
Hamizan

Comment: Missing CSS file. Try to use firebug or devtool.

Comment: class `div.itemIntroText` has attribute `font-weight: bold`.

Comment: @mokiSRB thank you. That solves the problem.

Comment: @RishiVishwakarma I understand on the missing css file. The problem with http://bit.ly/1TVrpB1 is that it only display part of the content. No links to any files in the source code. On the other hand, I don't see any options to include nor remove it on the content editor.